# Editar publicación con PHP MYSQL JQUERY

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto tipo estudio/prueba, y funciona todo OK, pero hay un problema/error.

El proyecto trata sobre una red social bastante básica, donde los usuarios pueden publicar posts (Tipo facebook), editar/eliminar/reportar, pero a la hora de editar/eliminar/reportar el post, surge un problema.

Yo, para obtener el post que van a editar uso SweetAlert2, JQUERY PHP y MYSQL, y la forma en la que lo hago es la siguiente.

En el mismo post que publico el usuario, tiene un menú donde puede elegir si editar/eliminar su propio POST, y para obtener el ID del post que el usuario va a editar, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="#" data-post-id="5">Editar</a>
```

**data-post-id**, es el id del POST. Al hacer clic, con JS obtengo lo que contiene data-post-id, y lo mando por Ajax a PHP para obtener el post a editar y abrirlo con SweetAlert, pero si abro la consola y cambio el valor de data-post-id, al mandarlo por ajax lógicamente no funcionaría como uno espera.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el usuario pueda editar el post, saber cual es el post que va a editar sin necesidad del atributo html?

*No pongo ningún código porque en realidad espero una explicación, no un código pre-hecho.*

Comment: No se puede ayudar del modo correcto sin ver como esta hecho. Hablar de supuestos no ayudaría en nada. Si te digo, que en la lista de publicaciones del usuario, tienes los 3 botones, editar/eliminar/reportar, obtienes el valor del id del post, y lo mandas para trabajarlo. Pero obvio, no tengo como ejemplificarlo, dado que no se que tienes tu

Comment: Solo es un e.target.getAttribute('data-id-post'). Como no hay nada de otro mundo y esta explicado, supuse que se podría entender que lo único que hay, es un Javascript que obtiene el valor de un atributo, y ese atributo lo mando por AJAX a un SELECT en un script PHP.

Comment: Es muy sencillo, antes de editar, verifica si la publicación pertenece al usuario, se supone que tienes esa información en sesión.

Comment: @Triby, Claro pero y el ID del post? Al hacer clic en editar, se supone que tengo que obtener ese POST mediante el ID, como hago? Porque si alguien por X motivo, entra al inspector y cambia el atributo, con verificar que sea del usuario o no, el post sigue obteniendo otro ID que no es

Comment: Mientras la publicación exista y le pertenezca al usuario no debería representar problema. Pero si aún te preocupa, podrías generar un token para cada publicación e incluirlo en la petición para comprobar que el ID no fue modificado.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que no trabajas con ningún framework de PHP sino que lo haces "a pelo".

En ese caso lo que tienes que hacer es comprobar (lo antes posible en tu código) que el id que recibes es un id de post que "pertenece" al usuario (dicho de otra forma, que el usuario ha creado).

En algún sitio de tu base de datos (probablemente en la tabla posts) tienes que tener una fila que enlace el post al usuario, de esta forma:

```
id (post) | user_id
----------------------------
    1           5
    2           5
    3           7
   ...         ...
```

Entonces, lo que tienes que comprobar es que el registro cuyo id se corresponde con el id que recibes, tiene un user_id que es igual al id del usuario que está realizando esa petición de borrado.